# Javascript on counting occurence of letter 'Z' in for loop textfield

Tags: javascript

Javascript on counting occurence of letter 'Z' in for loop textfield

I have like 50 text fields, user can enter up to 5 letter or number
I need a counter to count how many time did the letter "z" appear on all the text field.

I tried something like this, my textfield is with class **mytext** and id mytext_NUM, the textfield could be empty or with value.

```
var zoccur=0;

for(i=1;i<=50;i++)
{
$('.mytext').each(function () {
var value = document.getElementById("mytext_"+i).value;
zoccur = zoccur + value.match(/z/g);
})

alert("z occur is " + zoccur);
```

It return me **z is 0zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz null null null null repeatly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake.

```
// zoccur = zoccur + value.match(/z/g);           Number + Array
   zoccur = zoccur + value.match(/z/g).length; // Number + Number
```

Also, your `for` loop don't close (last `}` is missing).
Are you tring to do this?

```
var zoccur=0;
$('.mytext').each(function () {
    if(this.value.match(/z/g))
        zoccur += this.value.match(/z/g).length;
});
alert("z occur is " + zoccur);
```

Comment: +1 `.value.match(/z/g).length` is a good way to count the z's